# How to use phpthumb in phx:tv?

Tags: code-snippets, modx, television

Using MODX Evo 1.0.7

I am using phx:tv in a chunk like this:

```
[+phx:tv=`14?Photo`+]
```

Here is the phx:tv snippet (Source: http://wiki.modxcms.com/index.php/PHx/CustomModifiers#phx:tv)

```
    <?php
if(strlen($options )>0) {
    $data = explode("?",trim($options),2);
    $id= (!empty($data[0]) && is_numeric($data[0])) ? $data[0]: '';
    $tv= (!empty($data[1])) ? $data[1]: '';
    $result = $modx->getTemplateVar($tv, 'name', $id, 1);
    return $result['value'];
    }
?>
```

How can I use the phpthumb to resize the image in the Photo TV in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used phx or Evo for a long time, but you might try chaining it like this:

```
[+phx:tv=`14?Photo`:phpthumb=`w=450`+]
```